# improve understand of pointer syntax in char array

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this (working) code:

```
char * ptr = new char[10];
cin >> ptr;
```

the output of: `cout<<*(ptr+n)` is from the input.

why does `cin>>ptr` working, shouldn't it be `cin>>*ptr`?

Comment: `*ptr` is a single character, not an address, which means `cin` has no way of knowing where to put the subsequent characters.

Comment: There is an overload for `char*`, which gets selected in this case: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2

Comment: cin is intelligent when reading data to a variable and will automatically deduce the formatting to be applied (integer, float, char or string) in your case, ptr is a string (array of character) which means standard input will be interpreted as a string when calling cin >> ptr. *ptr is the first character of the array, which means cin >> *ptr will read a character to *ptr

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> ptr;
```

is syntactic sugar for this function call:

```
operator >>(std::cin, ptr);
```

This should make it more clear that there will be an overload set associated with the name `operator >>`. And indeed, looking at a [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2), we see e.g. this one:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits>
basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& operator>>( basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& st, CharT* s );
```

which is the function you're invoking. It takes a `std::basic_istream` instantiation (which `std::cin` is) and a pointer to the underlying character type (`ptr` in your case) and does the right thing.

When you instead invoke

```
operator >>(std::cin, *ptr);
```

you dereference the pointer to the `char` array, which returns a reference to the first element of this array. There is an overload that accepts a reference to a single `char` (#1 in the list of overloads) but it will do nothing but read a single `char` and that's it. Input other than the first `char` will be discarded.